# Does the keyword "await" from Async Await in JavaScript only work for promise?

Tags: javascript

When `await` is written inside an async function Like -

```
let x = await doSomething()
```

Does the `doSomething` function has to return a `Promise`?

Comment: Read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) _If the value is not a Promise, it converts the value to a resolved Promise, and waits for it._

Answer (score 1):

It may return anything because

```
let x = await doSomething()
// ... rest of your code

// is roughly equivalent

Promise
  .resolve(doSomething())
  .then(value => {
    let x = value

    // ... rest of your code
  })
```

But if `doSomething` is async it has to return something "thenable" so that `await` could actually work

```js
const doSomething = () => ({
  then(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn, 2000, 'hello')
  }
})

const run = async () => {
  let msg = await doSomething()
  
  console.log(msg)
}

run().then(() => console.log('Done'))
```